# why the same backbone trigger doesn't work at different place

Tags: backbone.js

As below code in an itemview, the first trigger "step:listTodos" works fine, but the second one doesn't work in function "onBeforeRender". I have printed the log, I am sure the second one can be called.

```
        events:{
        "click a.tabindex":"loadTodos"
    },

    loadTodos:function(){
        this.trigger("step:listTodos",this.model);
    },
    onBeforeRender: function(){
        if(this.model.get('index')===this.theStepIndex){
            console.log('before render');
            this.trigger("step:listTodos",this.model);
        }           
    },
```

add listen code:

```
stepsIndexView.on("childview:step:listTodos",function(childView,step){
                            console.log('trigger the list todo events');
                            var fetchingTodos = MySpace.request("entities:todos",ocase.get("_id"),step.get('index'));
                            $.when(fetchingTodos).done(function(todos){
```

Comment: Probably it doesn't happen because of `this.model.get('index') === this.theStepIndex`?

Comment: What's listening for the trigger?

Comment: this.model.get('index') === this.theStepIndex can be called because I can see the log printed in listen code as I just attached